# Selenium RC for test Flash

Tags: flash, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium rc and i need to test flash. I need to click Allow button on player .I just need some help getting started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

afaik this wont work because it relies on parsing the source-code to check whether the conditions were met.
hope this helps.

regards